# Change directory and execute file in one command

Tags: linux, bash, fedora, launcher, gnome-3

When I want to execute a file, it seems that I always have to first 'cd' into that file's directory before executing it, unless it fails on a can't-find-my-dataz type error.

How can I get around typing two commands to just execute a program?

Example:

```
cd /usr/local/bin/minecraft/
java -Xms512M -Xmx2048M -jar minecraft.jar
```

How can I make that into one line, so as I can put it as my Exec=*_* line when creating a custom launcher in Gnome3?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

`cd /usr/local/bin/minecraft/ && java -Xms512M -Xmx2048M -jar minecraft.jar` should do it

Comment: +1: The advantage of this command is that the `cd` fails, the java-command won't even be executed

Comment: I am doing the same using Python os.system("start /B start cmd.exe @cmd /k cd <my directory path> && <my second command>")
but the second command ends up being executing before my Change Directory command, hence fails, any workaround for this? Thanks

Answer (score 13):

I am answering this question again with some extension so that others may find this useful.

```
cd /usr/local/bin/minecraft/ && java -Xms512M -Xmx2048M -jar minecraft.jar
```

This command will do for sure. But after running this command, you will stay in `/usr/local/bin/minecraft/` directory. And, if you are using this command in a **bash script**, all the later commands will be executed in this directory.

If you want to run the command in your desired directory and get immediately back to where you were, enclose the command with **parenthesis**, i.e.,

```
(cd /usr/local/bin/minecraft/ && java -Xms512M -Xmx2048M -jar minecraft.jar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively (e.g. if passing somewhere else to be executed)

```
    sh -c 'cd /usr/local/bin/minecraft; java -Xms512M -Xmx2048M -jar minecraft.jar'
```